# I have position columns in pandas containing values from 1 to 15 and votes percentage columns containing values from 0 to 100

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find data where votes percentage is less than 10 between  position 1 and 2 in pandas,how do I do that ?

I have wrote this code and found out all 1 and 2 positions

```
df[(df['Position']==1) | (df['Position']==2)]
```

The data looks like this

```py
    Election_Year   Position    Name    Votes   Votes_per   Party   AC_name AC_No

0   2010            1    Rajesh Singh   42289   29.4    Janata Dal (United) Valmiki Nagar   1

1   2010            2   Mukesh Kumar    27618   19.2    Rashtriya Janata DalValmikiNagar    1

14  2010           1    Bhagirathi Devi 51993   41.5    Bharatiya Janta Party   Ramnagar    2

15  2010           2    Naresh Ram     22211    17.7    Indian National Congress    Ramnagar    2

31  2010          1 Satish Chandra     45022    38.1    Bharatiya Janta Party   Narkatiaganj    3
```

I can write this and find the answer for for two rows

```
a.Votes_per[0]-a.Votes_per[1]
```

Now how to find the data for all the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work,

```
df[df['Position']==1][ (df[df['Position']==1]['Votes_per'] - df[df['Position']==2]['Votes_per'] ) <10 ]
```

Comment: I need difference between position=1 and position=2 for all the rows

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question first time , Try this I have update the answer this should work.

Comment: Hi, if this answers your question it would really be helpful if you mark this as solution..( by clicking on tick sign in left)